# How to kill Absolute Killer?

Tags: tales-of-rays

In Tales of the Rays time limited event, Kaleidoscope of Distortion, how do you kill the boss Lv 22 Absolute Killer? All attacks only deal 1 damage and even with Mirage Art combo at 200% each attack still deals 1 damage. Moreover, there is only a slight window before it cast its killer move which would wipe out the team so I don't think running away would be the solution. Or is there any indicator that I can use that shows that it is about to usr that move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to see its feet. If there is a blue magic circle under it, the immediately use mirage art so that it is cancelled. Otherwise attack using normal attack or normal art.